# Creating redux exports at runtime

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

`redux-starter-kit` cleans up using redux somewhat.
I want to improve it further. So I try this:

```
import { createSlice } from 'redux-starter-kit'

export default knife = function(sliceName, initialState, actions) {
  return function() {
    eval(`export const #{sliceName} = createSlice(slice: sliceName,
      initialState: initialState, reducers: {})`)
  }
}
```

The goal is to customize the reducers: .. part according to my application needs (dynamic API calls based on the actions variable). That's the goal of this refactoring but not the goal of this question.

What I *hoped* to do was call, say in my `restaurantsSlice.js`

```
knife('restaurants', {allRestaurants: []}, {'addRestaurant', '/restaurants', 'POST", (state, action) => {...}})()
```

Hoping that it would eval the entire statement, making it the equivalent of doing

```
export const restaurantSlice = createSlice(
'slice': 'restaurant',
...
```

When I run this code, I get the error "Export declarations may only be made at top of module"

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just curious eval(`export const #{sliceName} = createSlice(slice: sliceName,
      initialState: initialState, reducers: {})`). why pound symbol "#" not dollar "$"

Comment: same issue unfortunately. I think I'm overengineering this and really what I need to do is just export the createSlice results. I'm still curious to know if I can do dynamic export like this

Comment: Having given my actual answer separately, I'm curious: what about RSK do you feel is not succinct so far?  What are you trying to abstract on top of `createSlice`?

Comment: API calls and success handling. I have to define createRestaurantSuccess = (state,action) in the reducer, then after the createSlice I have to const {createRestaurantSuccess} = restaurantSlice.actions    export const addRestaurant = (vars) => {return dispatch => { return apiPost(....

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this :(

- Using `eval()` is effectively never a good idea
- Per the error, the `export` keyword can only be used statically, at the top level of a file
- Meta-meta-programming like this will only cause problems for you down the road.

Start by writing out the actual code "by hand".  *If* you truly see a bunch of duplication across multiple files, then you can *consider* possibly trying to abstract it further.  (See Sandi Metz's post [The Wrong Abstraction](https://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction) for some strong arguments against trying to abstract too early.)

The Redux docs give [examples of writing reusable higher-order reducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic).  You could write reusable functions and include them in multiple slices, or potentially have a "higher order slice" function that accepts some options and calls `createSlice()`, but the actual code in that function needs to be *code*, not a string passed to `eval()`.

An example might look like this:

```js
const createFetchSlice = (sliceName, endpoint) => {
    const initialState = {
        loading: false,
        data: [],
    };

    const capitalizedName = capitalize(sliceName);

    const startedName = `create${capitalizedName}Started`;
    const successName = `create${capitalizedName}Success`'

    const slice = createSlice({
        slice: sliceName,
        initialState,
        reducers: {
            [startedName](state, action) {
                state.loading = true;
            },
            [successName](state, action) {
                state.data = action.payload;
                state.loading = false;
            },           
        }
    });

    const createItem = (values) => async dispatch => {
        const { [startedName] : fetchStarted, [successName] : fetchSuccess} = slice.actions;

        dispatch(fetchStarted());

        const response = await myAjaxLib.post(endpoint, values);

        dispatch(fetchSuccess(response.data));
    }

    slice.actions.createItem = createItem;

    return slice;
}
```

Comment: Disagree with point #3 :) but I'll accept for #2 and the redux link, thanks

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Yes - very similar to what I'm working with now. Thanks for the reference!
When I first checked the redux-starter-kit site they didn't have any good async examples so I didn't know to look in the combining reducers section.

Comment: I recently added [an "Advanced Tutorial" for RSK that covers working with thunks and TypeScript](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial).  The notion of combining reducers in different ways is plain Redux.